# Transaction was deadlocked - attempting to 'lock' records for processing

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have the following stored procedure that is being called by a number of instances of a a worker service. When the services first start, there is contention on the table and I get deadlocks and need to get rid;

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

    BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @Inserted TABLE (
        [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        [Status] INT NOT NULL,
        [LockDate] DATETIME NULL,
        [InternalId] BIGINT NULL,
        [SourceUpdated] BIT NOT NULL
    )

    UPDATE tm
            SET
                tm.LockDate = DATEADD(MINUTE, @LockDuration, GETDATE()), [ModifiedDate] = GETDATE()
            OUTPUT
                Inserted.[Id],
                Inserted.[Status],
                Inserted.LockDate,
                Inserted.InternalId,
                Inserted.SourceUpdated

            
            INTO @Inserted

            FROM  [Transactional].[Message] tm WITH (UPDLOCK)
            INNER JOIN
               (SELECT TOP 250 [Id] FROM  [Transactional].[Message]
            WHERE [Status] = 0 AND LockDate IS NULL
            ORDER by [ModifiedDate] ASC) tmc on tmc.Id = tm.Id


    COMMIT TRAN

    SELECT 
        [Id],
        [Status],
        [LockDate],
        [InternalId],
        [SourceUpdated]
    FROM
        @Inserted
```

The objective here is to lock 250 records for each process. The code is called from Entity Framework if that could be a factor;

```
var records = await _context.TransactionalMessages!
                            .FromSqlRaw($"EXEC [Records].[LockRecordsForProcessing]")
                            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: token);
```

The error I get is;

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 91) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Comment: What is @LockDuration set to?

You might want to look at your connection string for you application if you are doing your own transaction handling, and adjust timeouts for deadlock waits. Isolation level is set very high, so you will be encountering this lots if you have multiple processes hitting this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add UPDLOCK to the TOP 250 subquery too.  SERIALIZABLE by default reads with S locks, which will lead to deadlocks.  Basically SERIALIZABLE enforces isolation by creating deadlocks.

So you either need more restrictive locking than SERIALIZABLE, or you need to retry on deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is poor design but the following should get rid of the deadlocks without an explicit transaction:

```
DECLARE @OP TABLE
(
    [Id] bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Status] int NOT NULL,
    [LockDate] datetime NULL,
    [InternalId] bigint NULL,
    [SourceUpdated] bit NOT NULL
);
WITH Msg
AS
(
    SELECT TOP (250) Id, [Status], LockDate, InternalId, SourceUpdated
        ,ModifiedDate
    FROM Transactional.[Message] WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE [Status] = 0 AND LockDate IS NULL
    ORDER BY ModifiedDate
)
UPDATE Msg
SET LockDate = DATEADD(minute, @LockDuration, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ,ModifiedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OUTPUT Inserted.[Id], Inserted.[Status], Inserted.LockDate
    ,Inserted.InternalId, Inserted.SourceUpdated
INTO @OP;

SELECT Id, [Status], LockDate, InternalId, SourceUpdated
FROM @OP;
```

If you still have a lot of blocking, and want to keep this design pattern, you could also look at making Transactional.[Message] an In-Memory table.

Comment: OP: This is the correct answer. In this case there are no joins, and by default the table being updated will get a `UPDLOCK` anyway.